# Android buttons and touch events

Tags: android, motion-detection

Hi I am developing the pattern locker for android.
How or what method can I use to put the circles (pattern) i have drawn on the screen to be listened to, when touched and place them in an array?

I also have rectangles i have drawn as buttons..but the motion event is not listening to them.
please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the "dot swipe locker" is and a quick Google search didn't return anything relevant, but I can only assume you are trying to mimic the functionality of the Android pattern lock screen? Have you checked out the Android source code to see how they implement it?

http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#ohAXAHj6Njg/src/com/android/settings/ChooseLockPattern.java&q=ChooseLockPattern.java&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc

Comment: Is that what you're attempting to do, though? Mimic the exact functionality of the lock screen? If so, why reinvent the wheel? Why not just use the existing android code? It's licensed under Apache 2 so you should be fine just using it for your own purpose.